# How to count the number of items in a NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I want to *count* the number of items in a `NSArray` and perform some operation based on that. I know it's not a big deal but I couldn't get it.

Please give some suggestions.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

That's really simple:

```
int arrayLength = array.count;
```

Comment: To avoid a warning of NSUInteger do: int arrayLength = (int) array.count;

Answer (score 4):

`[yourNSArrayReference count]`; It is simple:=)

Answer (score 3):

Very simple:-

```
[*your array name* count];
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to just check

[array count];

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you declared your value as the correct type or else you will get: 
`Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'x' is disallowed with ARC`.

You could this...

```
num = [yourArray count];
```

and you'll get `Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int'`

**So then you should do this:**

```
num = (int)[allValues count];
```

**Or:**

```
num = (int)allValues.count;
```